# What is this mysterious red text on the embark screen?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

[image]
*(click image to enlarge)*

I was getting ready to embark, and I saw a strange thing on the local map (on the left) that looked like a square filled with "Ω" symbols. When I moved the local area on top of it, I saw "Lolokromlam" in red letters to the right.

What does this mean?

Comment: Is this your first fortress on this world? That really looks like a previous player fortress: default size, across a stream, tons of metals and no aquifer, a perfect site for a beginner fortress. You should be able to embark right next to it, even without Embark Anywhere.

Comment: @PaulZ Yes, it is my first fortress. No, I can't embark on it.

Comment: Really? Even if you move the embark area (with umkh) so it doesn't overlap the existing one? Anyway, I suggest moving east or west one region tile then. You should still be in the same biomes, so you have the same excellent fortress conditions.

Comment: @PaulZ No, as long as I move the local area (with umkh) so that it doesn't overlap the thingy, I can embark. (I moved to the right a bit and embarked there, with the same fortress conditions as the thingy :D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the name of a settlement, by the looks of it dwarven. You can see it on the local map. You can use [Embark Anywhere](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=21351.0) to embark on it, it might be fun, or you can look for another spot. You can read about the settlement in the Legends mode.

Comment: 1. What will happen if I embark on it? 2. By "fun", do you mean "fun" as in [this kind of Fun (link)](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Losing)? :P 3. Is [this what it is (link)](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Civilization#Mountain_Civilization_.28The_dwarves.29)?

Comment: The Ω symbols mean a dwarven settlement. Human settlements use ☼ or # or * or +.

Comment: 1. Probably not. 2. Looks that way. @PaulZ thanks!

Comment: Unless your civilization is at war with them (unlikely in case of dwarfs), they should leave you alone. But they will attack any invaders which gives you additional protection.

Comment: Hey everybody, notice that the embark option is grayed out? I'm pretty sure it's impossible to embark on an existing settlement without mods.

Comment: @Wutaz good point, updated answer.